# É correto versionar os arquivos das migrations e o arquivo de configuração?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, git, migrations

Os arquivos que fazem as migrations do banco de dados devem ser adicionados no versionamento com Git?

Estou usando o Phinx e tenho essa dúvida em relação as classes que representam as tabelas que são geradas por esta biblioteca. Me surgiu essa dúvida porque os arquivos gerados das migrations pelo Phinx contém nomes gerados aleatóriamente com números.

Também gostaria de saber se o arquivo de configuração do Phinx que é o arquivo phinx.yml (ou em outros formatos) deve ser versionado também. Ainda estou começando com migrations e ainda está vago para mim as práticas de como usar essa abordagem (e as suas vantagens).

Comment: até onde eu me lembro, esses números aleatórios são um timestamp (talvez até seja a própria data e hora, tipo 202005202009). Esse número é utilizado só para ordenar qual a migration mais nova. No mais a resposta do Lucas está bem clara.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logo na introdução da documentação do [Phinx](https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/intro.html), nos deparamos com a seguinte reflexão:

> Good developers always version their code using a SCM system, so why
>   don’t they do the same for their database schema?

Pensando que a filosofia da aplicação é manter o versionamento do banco de dados, então os arquivos de `migration`devem sim ser versionados, já que isso garante a **rastreabilidade** das alterações no banco de dados.

Quanto ao arquivo de configuração, eu suponho que você se refira ao arquivo que tenha os paths, environments, certo? Se não for, comenta por favor que se eu souber eu edito. Infelizmente não tenho reputação para comentar na sua pergunta ainda, por isso não conseguir sanar essa dúvida antes de formular a resposta.

Enfim, supondo que seja esse o arquivo de configuração citado, **sim**, esse arquivo pode ir ao git. Porém esse arquivo contém informações como senha do banco de dados que podem comprometer a sua segurança caso outro individuo tenha acesso, então, como é citado no warning dos [Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/configuration.html), devemos ter cuidado para não se tornar público, ainda mais o aplicativo em produção.

Caso tenha mais de um desenvolvedor trabalhando na aplicação, ou quando você precisa ter ambientes separados para propósitos separados (branchs, testes etc.) devemos utilizar a variável de ambiente `PHINX_ENVIRONMENT` para substituir o ambiente padrão. Para mais informações sobre isso, cheque mais [aqui](https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/configuration.html#environments).